# how to render a composite created by scripting?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, compositing-nodes

I tried my best to find the answer browsing the API doc and forums but here I'm stuck with quite an odd problem.
I'm developping an import addon wich I'd like to work as follows:
it opens a directory containing subfolders corresponding to each sequence of a movie. In each of these subfolders are still images constituting my sequences. 
For each sequence, it creates a new scene in blender and in each scene it adds and connects a bunch of compositing nodes (say one image sequence node , a keying node and a composite node ). Up to this point , the script works perfectly fine.

The problem is , when I try to render a scene the composite output is never taken into account and it only renders what's in the 3D view port, that is to say nothing. 
I checked in my scene render options that compositor is enabled for post-processing. And when I create the scene I always set the use_nodes option to True.

Here is the function used to create the scene and composite nodes.

Doesn't anyone has a clue why the composite nodes won't render?

```
def import_sequences(self,context):
    for s in os.listdir(self.directory):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(self.directory, s)):
            bpy.data.scenes.new(s)
            bpy.data.scenes[s].frame_end=len(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.directory,s)))
            bpy.data.scenes[s].render.resolution_percentage=100
            bpy.data.scenes[s].render.filepath=os.path.normpath(os.path.join(self.directory,"render",s))+os.sep
            bpy.data.scenes[s].use_nodes=True
            nodes=bpy.data.scenes[s].node_tree.nodes
            nodes.remove(nodes[nodes.find("Render Layers")])
            images_node=nodes.new("CompositorNodeImage")
            images=os.listdir(os.path.join(self.directory,s))
            images.sort()
            seq_im=load_image(images[0],os.path.join(self.directory,s))
            seq_im.source = 'SEQUENCE'
            seq_im.alpha_mode='PREMUL'
            images_node.image = seq_im
            images_node.frame_duration=len(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.directory,s)))
            if self.operation == "KEYING":
                keying_node=nodes.new("CompositorNodeKeying")
                bpy.data.scenes[s].node_tree.links.new(images_node.outputs[0],keying_node.inputs[0])
                bpy.data.scenes[s].node_tree.links.new(keying_node.outputs[0],nodes[nodes.find("Composite")].inputs[0])

    bpy.data.scenes.remove(bpy.data.scenes[bpy.data.scenes.find("Scene")])
```

Comment: Note: `bpy.data.scenes.remove(bpy.data.scenes[bpy.data.scenes.find("Scene")])` is redundant, you can do `bpy.data.scenes.remove(bpy.data.scenes["Scene"])`

Comment: haha thanks, I think it was about 4 or 5 am or something when I coded this XD though I still can't figure out where the problem is with my rendering. I must be missing some Scene parameter setting somewhere